# Issue after master rebase on a branch that was already branched

Tags: angular, git, merge, gitlab, rebase

In order :

- I created B1 from master and did some stuff.
- Then I openned a pull request and created B2 from B1 and did some stuff.
- Pull request validated, so I rebased master on B1 and merged B1 into master.
- Then I go back to B2 which does not have the result of the rebase. Even if I rebase master on B2, B1 commits are still here, duplicated.

Or

```
 - git checkout master
 - git pull
 - git checkout -b 'b1'
 - git commit...
 - git push
 - git checkout -b 'b2'
 - git commit...
 - git checkout b1
 - git rebase -i master
 - (Pull request and merge on gitlab)
 - git checkout b2
 - git rebase -i master
```

Result :

```
* (HEAD->B2 + origin/B2)
* b2 commit
* b2 commit
* 1bis b1 commit
* 2bis b1 commit
* * (origin/HEAD origin/master) - Merge B1 into master
| |\
|/ /
| * 1 b1 commit
| * 2 b1 commit
|/
*
|
```

How can I change/move B2 branch to master Head and remove duplicate commits ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be rebasing master on anything (except maybe origin/master, which should just be a fast forward merge anyway), you should be rebasing feature branches on master.

Since `b2` is based on `b1`, you need to rebase `b1` on `master`, then rebase `b2` on `b1`

- `git checkout b1`
- `get rebase -i master`
- `git checkout b2`
- `git rebase -i b1`
- drop duplicate commits in b2

Comment: Ah then your word-order is confusing. You rebased B1 on master, not master on B1. You should still be able to drop the commit on an interactive rebase

Comment: @An-droid based on your edit, you need to rebsae b2 on b1. `git checkout b2 && git rebase -i b1`. After b1 merges to master, then rebase b2 on master.

Answer (score 0):

Rebasing master branch to B2 branch will not apply here. I would suggest to just `cherry-pick` your changes from B2 branch to master

1. You need to undo everything that you did with B2 branch.
2. Revert master in a state where you merge B1 with master

Then

`git checkout master`

`git cherry-pick {commin-hash(s) of new changes from B2 branch}`